# Как указать циклу: что делать в конце строки?

Tags: python, циклы

Всем привет!
Проблема:
Вводятся три буквенные строки с хаотичными пробелами. Нужно эти строки преобразовать в УРЛ адреса. Т.е. все пробелы между ними заменить единичными дефисами.

Моя программа это делает, однак если в конце последней строки поставить пробел то выдает ошибку что стринг из аут оф рендж.

Вопрос:
Чем дополнить код, чтобы программа могла различать конец строки и ничего там не писать?

Небольшое пояснение:
Программа работает так:
-она принимает строки и делает из них лист.
-Создается пустая строка
-создается пустой список
-первый цикл перебирает строки в списке
-второй цикл перебирает символы и их индексы в строках -первый ИФ добавляет в пустую строку символ, если это символ или цифра
-второй ИФ добавляет в строку дефис, если сам символ это пробел, а следующий символ это не пробел. (вот тут то и косяк. значения n+1 в какой то момент просто не существует и получается ошибка. Не знаю, как это преодолеть)
-далее все строки добавляются в список
-список выводит только конкретную строку по каунту
-пустая строка обнуляется

```
lst_in = list(iter(input, ''))
r = ''
z = []
count = 0
for i in lst_in:
    for n,s in enumerate(i):
            if s.isdigit() or s.isalpha():
                r +=s
            if i[n].isspace() and not i[n+1].isspace():
                r += '-'
    z.insert(count,[r])
    print(*z[count])
    count +=1
    r = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
lst_in = list(iter(input, ''))
r = ''
z = []
count = 0
for i in lst_in:
    maxN = len(i) // Внимание <<
    for n,s in enumerate(i):
            if s.isdigit() or s.isalpha():
                r +=s             
            if i[n].isspace() and n<maxN and not i[n+1].isspace(): // Внимание <<
                r += '-'
    z.insert(count,[r])
    print(*z[count])
    count +=1
    r = ''
```